# use of deleted function error

Tags: c++, c++11

i have had a problem with `/usr/include/c++/4.6/ext/new_allocator.h:108:9: error: use of deleted function ‘SMIBQueue::SMIBQueue(const SMIBQueue&)’` with C++ eclipse.

and i am using `-std=c++0x` flag to use C++11

though i found the point that the error occur at, i don't know why.

this is header file

```
class SMIBQueue{
private:
    std::queue<unsigned char> exceptionQueue;
    std::queue<UserRequest*> userInputQueue;
    std::queue<LpRsp*> lpRspQueue;
    std::queue<LpCmd*> lpCmdQueue;

    std::mutex EvtQueueLock;
    std::mutex UserQueueLock;
    std::mutex LpRspQueueLock;
    std::mutex LpCmdQueueLock;
public:

    int evtGetItem(unsigned char &item);
    int evtPutItem(unsigned char item);
    int userGetItem(UserRequest*& item);
    int userPutItem(UserRequest* item);
    int lpGetItem(LpCmd*& queue_buf);
    int lpPutItem(LpCmd *queue_buf);
    int lpRspGetItem(LpRsp*& queue_buf);
    int lpRspPutItem(LpRsp *queue_buf);
    int lpRemoveQueuedInfo();
    int lpRspRemoveQueuedInfo();
};

class SMIBQueues{
public:
    static std::vector<SMIBQueue> smibQueues;
    static void queueInit(int numOfClient);
    static int evtGetItem(int sasAddr, unsigned char &item);
    static int evtPutItem(int sasAddr, unsigned char item);
    static int userGetItem(int sasAddr, UserRequest*& item);
    static int userPutItem(int sasAddr, UserRequest* item);
    static int lpGetItem(int sasAddr, LpCmd*& queue_buf);
    static int lpPutItem(int sasAddr, LpCmd *queue_buf);
    static int lpRspGetItem(int sasAddr, LpRsp*& queue_buf);
    static int lpRspPutItem(int sasAddr, LpRsp *queue_buf);
    static int lpRemoveQueuedInfo(int sasAddr);
    static int lpRspRemoveQueuedInfo(int sasAddr);
};
```

and this is the function that the error occur at

```
std::vector<SMIBQueue> SMIBQueues::smibQueues;

void SMIBQueues::queueInit(int numOfClient){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numOfClient; i++){
        SMIBQueue s;
        smibQueues.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

in this function, push_pack method makes the error.
when i eliminate the part, there is no problem while compiling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::mutex` has a deleted *copy-constructor*, this means that `SMIBQueue` will have its *copy-constructor* implicitly deleted since the compiler cannot generate one for you.

How would it go about copying a class which has members that cannot be copied? You will explicitly need to define your own *copy-constructor* if you want `SMIBQueue` to be *copyable*.

---

**WHERE DOES MY CODE REQUIRE A COPY TO BE MADE?**

When you are calling `smibQueues.push_back (s)` a copy of `s` will be stored inside `smibQueues`, which requires (the implicitly deleted) *copy-constructor*.

You can circumvent this **specific** problem by using `smibQueues.emplace_back ()` to *default-construct* a `SMIBQueue` directly inside your `smibQueues` (ie. `std::vector`).

<sup>**Note**: Just keeo in mind that `smibQueues` might require `SMBIQueue` to be copyable/movable during other operations, such as if it tries to resize the underlying buffer, etc.</sup>

---

**RECOMMENDED SOLUTION**

Define your own *copy-constructor* if you plan to use it in contexts which require copying, but do keep in mind that `std::mutex` is neither copyable or movable, according to the Standard.

Comment: Or just call `smibQueues.resize(smibQueues.size() + numOfClient)` to implicitly construct all the extra entries.

Comment: Even with `emplace_back()` the problem will persist. Vectors still need to be able to copy or move their objects during resizing (moving being preferred in C++11, obviously). Once again, however, `std::mutex` is required to be *neither*, and in fact mandated by the standard to be just the opposite. C+11 30.4.1.2 [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex] dictates specifically that "The mutex types shall not be copyable or movable." Punch up the code for the generic `emplace_back()` with the OP's class def as-presented and it still won't work.

Comment: @WhozCraig sure, doing a resize the elements must be *movable/copyable*, I was directly addressing the problem with the line in question. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp Sure. Btw, `smibQueues.emplace_back()` (empty parens important) *will* work with a `std::deque<>`.