# Crypto++ AutoSeededRandomPool copy constructor implicitly deleted

Tags: c++11, constructor, crypto++, dsa

My question is about a crypto++ constructor and why it is in the state of being "implicitly deleted" even though it follows the examples provided in the documentation.

I am trying to go off of the code provided by the example on [Crypto++'s documentation to create a digital signature key pair](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm), but I am having trouble calling the constructor for AutoSeededRandomPool objects.
Here is the command I am calling to the terminal:

```
g++  -I /usr/local/include/ -l cryptopp -std=c++11 -c -o build/account.o src/account.cpp
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool',
note: copy constructor of 'AutoSeededRandomPool' is implicitly deleted because base
class 'CryptoPP::RandomPool' has a deleted copy constructor
```

Additionally, I get this unusual message:

```
clang: warning: -lcryptopp: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

Here is are the files I use to generate the public/private key pair. They pretty much follow the example:

```
DSA::PrivateKey create_private_key(AutoSeededRandomPool rng) {
  DSA::PrivateKey private_Key;
  private_Key.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 1024);
  return private_Key;
}

DSA::PublicKey create_public_key(DSA::PrivateKey private_key, AutoSeededRandomPool rng) {
  DSA::PublicKey public_Key;
  public_Key.AssignFrom(private_key);
  if (!private_key.Validate(rng, 3) || !public_Key.Validate(rng, 3))
  {
    throw std::runtime_error("DSA key generation failed");
  }
  return public_Key;
}
```

I declare and initialize the `AutoSeededRandomPool` object in a constructor as follows:

```
account::account() {
  balance = 0;
  AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
  private_key = utils::create_private_key(rng);
  public_key = utils::create_public_key(private_key, rng);
}
```

I have linked in the libraries necessary for this, and I am linking them in when I call g++. Additionally, if anyone knows if there are any more detailed examples of Crypto++ code, those resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try passing the parameters by reference rather than value? If you pass them by value, that implicitly calls the copy constructor, and apparently they aren't copyable.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I did not know that fact about copy constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  g++ -I /usr/local/include/ -l cryptopp -std=c++11 -c -o build/account.o src/account.cpp
> ```
>
> clang: warning: -lcryptopp: 'linker' input unused

Try:

```
g++ ... src/account.cpp -c -o build/account.o
```

Omit `-l cryptopp`. It is only needed during link.

---

> ```
> DSA::PrivateKey create_private_key(AutoSeededRandomPool rng) {
>   DSA::PrivateKey private_Key;
>   private_Key.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 1024);
>   return private_Key;
> }
> ```
>
> error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of
>   'CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool', note: copy constructor of
>   'AutoSeededRandomPool' is implicitly deleted because base class
>   'CryptoPP::RandomPool' has a deleted copy constructor

Pass `rng` by reference:

```
DSA::PrivateKey create_private_key(AutoSeededRandomPool& rng) {
    ...
}
```

Do it in both `create_private_key` and `create_public_key`.

The reason is, `AutoSeededRandomPool` base class is `RandomPool`, and `RandomPool` base class is `NotCopyable`. `NotCopyable` hides copy and assignment by making them private. I guess that's where the "implicit" part comes from the compiler error.

```
class RandomPool : public RandomNumberGenerator, public NotCopyable
{
    ...
}
```

---

***IF*** you don't want to pass by reference, then create one locally. There are certain reasons why you ***want*** to do this when generating a private key. See [Cryptography Engineering: Design Principles and Practical Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470474246) for more details.

```
DSA::PrivateKey create_private_key() {
  AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
  DSA::PrivateKey private_Key;
  private_Key.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 1024);
  return private_Key;
}
```

---

Related, when you link, place `-lcryptopp` at the end of the command. Something like:

```
g++ -o myprog -std=c++11 build/account.o build/some-other-object.o -lcryptopp -pthread
```

Order matters because LD is a single pass linker. Libraries always go at the end. You can work around it with options like `-(` and `--start-group`, but its easy to remember to place libraries at the end.

---

Some more of the C++11 backstory is, when you experience `copy constructor implicitly deleted`, you usually define one in your class. See, for example, [Use of deleted function error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23951989/608639).

However, in the case of `AutoSeededRandomPool`, we don't want them copied for several reasons. The Crypto++ `Algorithm` class, which is a base class of `AutoSeededRandomPool`, has a `Clone`. However, we don't want the generator cloned, either. Again, see [Cryptography Engineering: Design Principles and Practical Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470474246).